# How to reload or refresh page on screen pull down only on webview just like chrome App on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The below code is used to generate an app for `Webview`.
Can someone guide me on how to implement page reload on screen pull down?
I want to achieve this because sometimes due to no internet connection `Webview` returns an error and when the user turns on the internet connection the page remains as it is. I want user to have the ability to reload the page on screen pull down just like how it is done on chrome app.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: BackButton());
  }
}

class BackButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BackButtonState createState() => _BackButtonState();
}

class _BackButtonState extends State<BackButton> {
  DateTime backbuttonpressedTime;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 0),
        child: AppBar(
          title: Text(""),
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        ),
      ),
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: onWillPop,
        child: WebviewScaffold(
          url: "https://theonlineindia.co.in/",
          hidden: true,
          initialChild: Container(
            child: const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.deepPurple)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> onWillPop() async {
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();

    //ifbackbuttonhasnotbeenpreedOrToasthasbeenclosed
    //Statement 1 Or statement2
    bool backButton = backbuttonpressedTime == null ||
        currentTime.difference(backbuttonpressedTime) > Duration(seconds: 2);
    if (backButton) {
      backbuttonpressedTime = currentTime;
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Double tap to exit the app",
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          textColor: Colors.white);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: This package does exactly what you want: https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh Just reload the webview and you've refreshed the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Uni mentioned above, [pullToRefresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh) plugin is your solution here. It has all required methods you need. You just need to call the webviews reload function inside `_onRefresh()` to do your job.